# Nginx show custom error page upon return error code?

Tags: nginx, block, custom-error-pages

Inside the `server` block I have the following error page defined:

```
error_page 406 /abs/path/to/error.ie.html;
```

Also, the following condition to block IE:

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* (MSIE|Trident|wget|curl|libwww-perl) ) {
    return 406;
}
```

It successfully blocks the execution of the default `location`, but returns the nginx 406 error page instead of the custom html.

How can I return the custom html?

Comment: What is `/abs/path/to/`? Is it a URI or the document root? The `error_page` directive requires a URI.

Comment: It is an URI and the error_page works in other cases: then the proxy unable to find the backend servers or when they throw an error.

Comment: Is the “if block” in the server block or a location?

Comment: It is in the server block.